# GStreamer UDPSink Not Outputting Anything

Tags: video, udp, streaming, gstreamer

Hey I'm trying to experiment with `GStreamer`'s `udpsink`on Mac OS Catalina. I'm using the following commands to do this.
On one terminal (mock server) I do this:

`GST_DEBUG=udpsink:5  gst-launch-1.0 -v audiotestsrc ! udpsink port=5400`

and on the other (client) I do this

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5400 ! autoaudiosink`

I get nothing on the client side and it seems like when I do a `tcpdump` by invoking the following command

`sudo tcpdump -i en0 -s 0 udp port 5400 -vv -X`

nothing is detected there either. Furthermore, I'm getting no debug messages from udpsink. I tried sticking in a `identity dump =1`  right before the `udpsink` to make sure it's receiving stuff and it is. I also tried turning off the firewall to no avail. Does anybody have any other suggestions? I came across this when trying to run gstreamer's webrtc examples on my machine which also yielded similar results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
udpsink inherits multiudpsink.
This works:

```
export GST_DEBUG="multiudpsink:5"
```